# Razor Binding Value to CSS Class for Glyphicon

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an anchor tag which is generated via Razor:

```
<a data-parent="#accordion" href=@itm.LinkUrl>
  @itm.ItemName
  <span class=@itm.Glyph></span>
</a>
```

The value for @itm.Glyph is **

> glyphicon glyphicon-envelope pull-right

**

The glyphicon is not rendering because inspecting the HTML, what happens is:

```
<span class="glyphicon" glyphicon-envelope="" pull-right=""></span>
```

I tried to use:

```
<span class=@Html.Raw(@itm.Glyph)></span>
```

and

```
<span class=@String.Format("{0}", @itm.Glyph)></span>
```

But it produces the same result.

Anyone point me to what I may be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around the razor item:

```
<a data-parent="#accordion" href="@itm.LinkUrl">
  @itm.ItemName
  <span class="@itm.Glyph"></span>
</a>
```

Note that you also forgot it at the href attribute.

Comment: Oh, such an oversight for me. Thanks for pointing out. I'll accept this in a few minutes.